# Jenkins Delivery Pipeline Error " Error communicating to server!"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was using the delivery pipeline in jenkins and it was working fine but when I am going to create new pipeline it giving the error like.

"Error communicating to server!"

NOTE: My Jenkins is running fine with build-pipeline.

Could you pls provide your inputs why is happening...

Answer (score 0):

Need to re-install the delivery plugin and restart the Jenkins. Issue resloved.